# Method to get parameters send it in Ajax request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

Is there method te get parameters send it with ajax method on vue-tables-2 component ?

query: 
limit: 25
ascending: 1
page: 1
byColumn: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `requestAdapter` in vue-tables-2 is what you're looking for

example:

```
var vueTablesOptions = {
    requestAdapter: (data) => {
        // massage data
        return data;
    },
}
```

The author has a much better example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/matfish2/js4bmdbL/)